# How to create dynamic xml element using recursive function call in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to convert one xml format to another specified format by using xslt. This is my Xml File.I have to create some dynamic xml element by using some type of recursive call in xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text1-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text2-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text3-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text4-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text5-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text6-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text7-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text8-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text9-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text10-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>


</w:body>
</w:document>
```

**And my required output xml is :**

```
<Document>
      <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph> 
      <Heading1>
         <Title>Text2-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph> 
         <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph> 
         <Heading2>
            <Title>Text5-</Title>
            <Paragraph>Text6-</Paragraph> 
            <Heading3>
                <Title>Text7-</Title>
                <Paragraph>Text8-</Paragraph>  
            </Heading3>         
         </Heading2>
      <Heading1>
      <Heading1>
         <Title>Text9-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text10-</Paragraph> 
       <Heading1>      
</Document>
```

Please Guide me a way to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs w mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
        <xsl:element name="Heading{$level}">
          <Title><xsl:value-of select="r/t"/></Title>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="document">
  <Document>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1)"/>
  </Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <Paragraph>
    <xsl:value-of select="r/t"/>
  </Paragraph>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied with Saxon 9.4 on your sample input document I get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
   <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph>
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Text2-</Title>
      <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph>
      <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph>
      <Heading2>
         <Title>Text5-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text6-</Paragraph>
         <Heading3>
            <Title>Text7-</Title>
            <Paragraph>Text8-</Paragraph>
         </Heading3>
      </Heading2>
   </Heading1>
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Text9-</Title>
      <Paragraph>Text10-</Paragraph>
   </Heading1>
</Document>
```

Comment: I have put your xslt file in my vs-2010 project folder.When i opening in vs-2010 then it says " 'xpath-default-namespace' is not yet implemented" and also 'xsl:function' is not yet implemented.can i run this xslt file by using VS-2010 or do i need to include anything

Comment: You tagged your post as XSLT 2.0 so I wrote an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet. To run XSLT 2.0 you need an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or AltovaXML.

Comment: @Matrin Honnen : Very Sorry... I want to run this file in VS-2010.How can i convert this code to run on my requirement

Comment: Well both Saxon 9 and XmlPrime are usable in .NET code you can write in Visual Studio. Even AltovaXML can be run in .NET applications by using COM interop. I don't know whether there are any plugins for VS 2010 to apply XSLT 2.0 without writing code, maybe someone else can help with that. As for solving the problem with XSLT 1.0, that is difficult as there is no easy match in XSLT 1.0 for the `for-each-group` with `group-starting-with` and a recursive function. Again I hope someone else comes along later to help with that, I don't have the time to try to solve that problem with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: It's time you moved to more modern tools. XSLT 1.0 was superseded over five years ago. Using 2.0 gives a vast productivity improvement. There are some environments where it's still not available, but .NET isn't one of them.

Comment: @ Can anyone suggest me a plug in or some tools that will be used in .Visual Studio - 2010(.net 4) environment?

Comment: @MartinHonnen : Thanks it works good in xslt2.0.Thanks a lot.Martin, Suppose if my Second <w:p> element's having <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /></w:pPr>. Then it wont work properly.I want to create a Heading2 element then proceed the same logic...Could you please help me with that

Comment: Suppose if my Second <w:p> element's having <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /></w:pPr>. Then it wont work properly.I want to create a Heading2 element then proceed the same logic...can anybody please help me with that

Comment: Saravan, if the input you have now is more complex and you have more complex requirements I think it is best if you post a new question where you show details of the more complex input and the desired output. You can link in your new question to this question but I think a new question with well-formatted details is better than trying to exchange code details in comments.